Sticky table header overlaps with the navbar
I am making a website using Bootstrap and the library DataTables (https://datatables.net/). The issue I am facing now is that as you can see, the sticky table header is working, but since the nav bar is also sticky, they overlap. I want that the navbar "pushes down" the table header somehow.
Start:

Scroll down:

How could I avoid the overlapping? I would not like to use any hacky solution such as adding a fixed margin/padding to elements.
HTML definition of the table:
<table id="measurementsTable" class="cell-border stripe border w-100">

JS code:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let measurementsTable = new DataTable('#measurementsTable', {
        fixedHeader: true,
        fixedColumns: true,
        scrollX: true,
        layout: {
            topStart: {
                info: {
                    text: '_TOTAL_ filters',
                }
            },
            bottomStart: null,
        },
        ordering: false,
        paging: false,
    });
});


According to their docs you can try
new DataTable('#myTable', {
    fixedHeader: {
        headerOffset: 50
    }
});

Or even calculate height of navbar and use that:
new DataTable('#myTable', {
    fixedHeader: {
        headerOffset: $('.navbar').outerHeight()
    }
});

